# What is @AuthenticationPrincipal alternative for micronaut?

Tags: java, authentication, micronaut

I'm trying to get `UserDetails` object like below. But, I have some difficulties and impossible to get `UserDetails` object, so there is only `JSONObject` in `authentication.getAttributes()`. Is there any alternative way in micronaut to get `UserDetails` object?

Custom `UserDetails` object:

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {
    private Account account;

    public MyUserPrincipal(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return getAccount();
    }

}
```

Rest api:

```
//micronaut
@Post(value = "/echo")
@Status(HttpStatus.OK)
public Long echo(@Nullable Authentication authentication) {
    Long accountId = (Long)((JSONObject)authentication.getAttributes().get("account")).get("id");
    return accountId;
}
```

For example in Spring Security it is easy with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation in parameter.

Rest api:

```
@GET
public ResponseEntity<?> echo(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserPrincipal user) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user.getAccount().getAccountId(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: "It is not easy to get UserDetails in micronaut" - Not a great way to begin a question that is really asking if there is an easy way to get UserDetails in Micronaut.

Comment: thanks, I've corrected

Comment: You also didn't show the equivalent of what you're expecting. How would you retrieve the account id in the spring example

Answer (score 4):

If you are still looking for a solution, here is what works.
    You have to provide an implementation of `JwtAuthenticationFactory` and replace default `DefaultJwtAuthenticationFactory`.

Something like this (code below is in Kotlin):

```
@Singleton
@Replaces(bean = DefaultJwtAuthenticationFactory::class)
class CustomJwtAuthenticationFactory() : JwtAuthenticationFactory {
    override fun createAuthentication(token: JWT?): Optional<Authentication> {
        try {
            val builder = JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
            builder.claim("username", token?.jwtClaimsSet?.getStringClaim("username"))

            return Optional.of(AuthenticationJWTClaimsSetAdapter(jwtClaims))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException("ParseException creating authentication", e)
        }
    }
}
```

All claims added using the builder will get added in the `Authentication` object and can be accessed in any controller eg:

```
@Get("/hello-world")
fun hello(authentication: Authentication): String =
    authentication["username"] as String
```

If you are using Kotlin, use could also add extension methods on Authentication method to fetch attributes that you add to Authentication class eg:
`fun Authentication.username(): String = this.attributes["username"]`

Note: `username` is just an example. It is available as `name` instance variable on instance of Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

UserDetails does not exist after authentication. The only object available is the Authentication. If you want to standardize the code you have above you could create a bean that handles injection of that specific property.

You could use an annotation to designate the injection by creating an annotation along with an implementation of `AnnotatedRequestArgumentBinder`. Something like the following:

```
public class Temp implements AnnotatedRequestArgumentBinder<YourAnnotation, Long> {

    @Override
    public Class<YourAnnotation> getAnnotationType() {
        return YourAnnotation.class;
    }

    @Override
    public BindingResult<Long> bind(ArgumentConversionContext<Long> context, HttpRequest<?> source) {
        if (source.getAttributes().contains(OncePerRequestHttpServerFilter.getKey(SecurityFilter.class))) {
            final Optional<Authentication> authentication = source.getUserPrincipal(Authentication.class);
            if (authentication.isPresent()) {
                return () -> (Long)((JSONObject)authentication.getAttributes().get("account")).get("id");
            }
        }

        return ArgumentBinder.BindingResult.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not good, that's why, we send `UserDetails` to JWT in `AuthenticationProvider` (`return Flowable.just(new UserDetails((String) authenticationRequest.getIdentity(), new ArrayList<>()))`), but couldn't get.

Comment: I don't need only `accountId`, whole `UserDetails` object I need.

Comment: Maybe I must register this binder. @JamesKleeh how can I register this binder?